# Did James want to kill or transform Bella?

Tags: twilight

In the first Twilight movie, James, a vampire specializing in tracking, bit Bella in the ballet studio. I'm confused about the process to feed on someone or transform someone into a vampire in Twilight:

**1. Did he want to kill *(feed on)* her? Or transform her into a vampire?**

**2. Also why was Edward the only one who could save her from the venom? Why didn't the doctor, who seems more experienced, extract the poison?**

/!\ Don't spoil me for the other movies I didn't watch them yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**He just bites down at first.**

His real game is provoking Edward. (Bella is unimportant so will become first lunch and then a statistic... after the fight.)

From the script:

```
      JAMES
      Sorry. But you really made it too easy.          
      ....
      So to make things more entertaining, 
      I'm going to make a little film of our 
      time together.
      ....
      He will. His rage will make for 
      more interesting sport than his 
      feeble attempt to protect you.
```

Then Edward arrives.

```
      Looking directly at Edward with a sinister grin -- he SINKS 
      HIS TEETH into Bella's hand! She SCREAMS in agony.
```

**Edward extracting the venom.**

After the fight only dr. Cullen, Edward and Alice are able to control themselves enough to be able to help. Dr. Cullen is busy stemming Bella's blood loss.  Edward is the only one having a prayer of succeeding to suck out the tainted blood, *and then stop drinking*.

Abbreviated script:

```
      BACK ON BELLA -- as Edward reaches her side. Dr. Cullen works 
      fast to assess her wounds, focusing on a massive bleed from her 
      leg. But clearly her hand hurts the most. She writhes in pain. 
      Dr. Cullen applies pressure to the gash on her thigh -

      DR. CULLEN
      Her femoral artery's been severed. 
      She's losing too much blood.
      You have to make a choice. Either let the change happen -

      EDWARD
      No!

      ALICE
      It's going to happen. I've seen it -        

      DR. CULLEN
      Alice, find me a tourniquet. A rag, a shirt.

      Alice holds her nose and avoids the blood as she rips the 
      sleeve off her blouse and kneels to aid Dr. Cullen. 

      EDWARD
      What's the other choice? You said -

      DR. CULLEN (to Alice)
      Tighter, above the knee -

      DR. CULLEN
      You can try to suck the venom out. 

      EDWARD
      I -- won't be able to stop -

      DR. CULLEN
      Find the will to stop. But choose, she only has minutes left.
```

Comment: I understand now, much appreciated.

Comment: @MOTZI glad to help. Have fun watching the movies!

Comment: The book goes a tad different, involving feeding frenzy, but Bella's survival chances are very similar.